# Solve $\int _0^2t^2e^{-t}\cos\left(n\frac{\pi }{2}t\right)dt\:$ using Laplace

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

```
Problem: Solve the following integral
```

> $$\int _0^2t^2e^{-t}\cos\left(n\frac{\pi }{2}t\right)dt\:$$

```
My question
```

> Can I solve this integral using the Laplace transformation, if so what would be a great start to approach this integral?

Comment: Compare the given integral to the definition of Laplace transform. What parts are different/missing?

Comment: The definition states $F\left(s\right)=\int _0^{\infty }\:e^{-st}f\left(t\right)dt$, therefore the upper bound should be $+\infty$, $s=1$ and $f\left(t\right)=t^2cos\left(n\frac{\pi }{2}t\right)$.

Comment: Almost, with that choice of $f(t)$, you require $g(t)$ such that$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st} g(t)\,dt = \int_0^2 e^{-st} f(t)\,dt\implies g(t)=\begin{cases}f(t)&0\le t\le2\\0&t>2\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oooh, I'll try it out now, thank you